# Https Certificate Installation on TIBCO

Tags: java, ssl, webserver, tibco, tibco-business-works

We have a Java based application that connects to a web server to download a file. This Java based application is being invoked from within TIBCO which serves as a middleware. Recently, the web server is migrated to use Https certificate. So the URL would contain the Https protocol in it.

If we run the application as a standalone Java client, it works as long as I have imported the Https certificate into the Java keystore. We then moved the application onto TIBCO and installed the certificates onto the TIBCO BW. With this, we are still facing the login problems.

In the past we have noticed that we get a PEER Not Authenticated error message if the JRE cacerts keystore file is not imported with the web server certificate. But once we import it, it always worked fine. With TIBCO, we installed it in TIBCO BW. Still the issue persist.

We also have a JRE on that server where TIBCO is running. Are we expected to import the certificate into the JRE keystore as well?.

Really need your inputs as I am not familiar with TIBCO extensively. I am googling and exploring other ideas as we speak. But any pointers are definitely helpful.

thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the "peer not authenticated" error but if you wonder how to install SSL certificates in TIBCO BW, I suggest you have a look at the following tutorial (assuming you are working with BW 5.x):

https://tibcology.wordpress.com/2017/03/19/invoking-a-web-service-over-https-with-bw-5-x/